# Making parents path as a variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just wanted to ask a better way to track parent paths in jQuery, currently I do this.

```
$('.qBox em a').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.overlayIMG').fadeIn(100);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.overlayIMG').fadeOut(100);
    }
);
```

But I wanted to do something like this (the code below doesn't work for some reason that I don't know). I'm not sure how to search this problem properly, I already tried tracking parents and parent paths but can't find the answer, so I'll bother you for the moment.

```
$('.qBox em a').hover(
    var biggerImage = $(this).parent().parent().find('.overlayIMG');
    function(){
        biggerImage.fadeIn(100);
    },
    function(){
        biggerImage.fadeOut(100);
    }
);
```

This is the HTML Markup

```
<div class="qBox">
    <em>
          <img src="images/homepagethumbOL.png" class="overlayedIcon">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/sample_box.jpg"></a>
    </em>
    <span>
        <h3><a href="#">Article Title Looks Like This or Longer</a></h3>
        <p>Curabitur zblandit tempus porttitor. Donec ullamcorper.</p>
        <a href="#">view <i>45</i> comments</a>
        </span>
    <img src="images/sampleBig.jpg" class="overlayIMG one">
</div>
```

Comment: please share the html markup so that we can suggest something

Comment: your second option is syntactically incorrect

Comment: Yeah, that's my problem. I don't know the proper way to do it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `each()` to iterate over elements and find `.overlayIMG` only once:

```
$('.qBox em a').each(function(){
    var overlay = $(this).parent().parent().find('.overlayIMG');

    $(this).hover(
        function(){
            $(overlay).fadeIn(100);
        },
        function(){
            $(overlay).fadeOut(100);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: This works like a charm, I've been using the old method for quite some time now and I really find it unclean. So I decided to ask it here. Thanks guys! Appreciate your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a variable in the place you've done it - it's incorrect syntactically. However if you declare it outside of the hover scope you can't use the `this` keyword.

You could used jQuery's `data()` functionality:

```
$('.qBox em a').hover(
function ()
{
    var data = $(this).data(this, "data");
    if (data.img == undefined)
    {
        data = { img: $(this).parent().parent().find('.overlayIMG') };
        $(this).data(this, "data", data);
    }

    $(data.img).fadeIn(100);
},
function ()
{
    var data = $(this).data(this, "data");
    $(data.img).fadeOut(100);
});
```

This will store the image reference against the `a` but will only store it when the hover function is fired.